# Lets tighten the reins of the tags

Tags: discussion, tags

First of all, I hate dealing with troubles and problems, especially if they could be averted before hand. And tags will always become a problem of all SE sites. If you have come from any site you know that there's always drama about tags ([we are already asking for some tags to be blacklisted](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/)) so lets prevent the problem before it becomes one. Here some ground rules:

### Duplicate tags:

Apparently someone through that [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) was not enough and created [floss](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floss) and also suggested a tag excerpt. Please don't do this. If another tag already means what you are trying to tag use that tag.

### Hardware tags

I expect some macair, iPod, iPad, blackberry, dell, et all tags. Remember that software [depends greatly in the OS](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-specific-should-the-os-tag-be) your device is running hence [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios), [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx), [blackberry-os](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackberry-os) are more relevant and useful tags. Nobody needs to know what hardware you have running your OS on.

### Tag + space + tag

This is one of the most problematic... because people don't understand how tagging works. An user looking for a music editor will tag his question as [music](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) + [editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editor) = [madness](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/madness). Teach users about the use of the hyphen so those [music](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) becomes [music-editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-editor), [music-player](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-player), [music-production](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-production). The same applies to broader topics like: image, picture, photo, sound, text, etc.

I haven't found another example of something that is already happening but I presume other possible problems might occur in the long run.

Comment: ipod/ipad/iphone, and similarly android-tablet or something might actually be useful *in some rare cases*, as not all apps are available on both form factors. But this should be exception, not the standard.

Comment: I agree with @Olli, for the scenarios he mentioned. ios-iphone, ios-ipad (maybe even ios-ipadmini), android-tablet, or android-phone would be helpful on occasion.  There is no need for ios-universal as the generic [tag:ios] tag would suffice.

Comment: What if hardware doesn't matter much to you? I own multiple computers with various OS's, so when I ask [what some good mapping software for an RPG would be](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/923/what-mapping-software-can-print-large-battlemaps-for-rpgs), I don't really care what system you tell me for, and I wouldn't expect to create a separate question for each OS.

Comment: @Sterno I presume you would ask for OS independient stuff, no?

Comment: While basically agreeing, there's one problem with the last group: do we really want separate "abc-client"/"abc-server" tags? We've already got several of them. If I'm e.g. looking for a mail-server replacement, using the tags "mail"+"server" would be quite a convenient way to get them all. I remember we've had that topic already here on meta. To me, "server" falls into the same category as e.g. "desktop-client" and "web-app" – a group clearly missing here.