# The sound of tagging - sorting out the plethora of audio related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

We have multiple audio related tags:

- [music](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)
- [music-production](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-production)
- [audio](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [composing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composing)

Out of these tags, some of them are quite clear:

[music-production](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-production) clearly covers virtual instruments, digital audio workstations, sequencing software, etc.

[music](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) seems to be at the more average end user end of the scale - media players, media library software, that sort of thing.

And then some of them are a little off key and probably need fixing:

[audio](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) appears tagged with one of the other tags in all but one instance

[composing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composing) covers sequencing, essentially - I think this should be merged into [music-production](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-production) and a synonym created.

Comment: Yeah, let's avoid [tag:audio] which is too broad. We have [tag:audio]=[tag:sound] on [unix.se] and we sometimes regret this too-broad tag.

Comment: We also have a `sound` tag.

Comment: Related meta: [What is the difference between sound and audio?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1215/3474)

Answer (score 5):

- [audio](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) should be reserved for software dealing with audio capabilities of the computer (e.g., turning audio on/off, speaker/headphone driver type software, volume controllers, recording sound) instead of being used as a super-umbrella-tag. Possible other aliases: [speakers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speakers), [headphones](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones), [audio-capabilities](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-capabilities). May be also alias [sound](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) and [sound-recording](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-recording).

  Ex: [Android app to silence the phone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/android-app-to-silence-the-phone)
- [music-production](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-production) should stay as you proposed, with alias [composing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composing).
- [sound-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-editing) should be for things that let you edit sound files.
- [music](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) should stay , with alias [music-players](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-players). Or may be better yet, reverse the two.

Comment: We also have a `sound` tag, where would you put this?

Comment: okay. Would you add this to the answer (synonym `sound` to `audio`) so its complete?

Comment: I added a list of examples in my answer. Would you copy it and propose what tags should be used in your scheme so they can be compared?

Comment: Related meta: [What is the difference between sound and audio?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1215/3474)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following definition (and will compare it to "CSV-File"):

1. Audio is the over arching word containing everything. (compare "File")
2. Sound is the digital representation of audible things. (compare "Text-File")
3. Music is the specific element in the realm of Sound. (compare "CSV-File")

Also I feel strongly with this Meta: [Lets tighten the reins of the tags](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/lets-tighten-the-reins-of-the-tags) "Tag + Space + Tag" = Bad.

Thus the following tag changes:

1. [audio](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio), [music](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and [sound](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) should be treated as a "topic tag" like [programming](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming), [video](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) etc. and therefore discouraged (maybe even removed & blacklisted).
2. "audio-" tags should be used in the border cases where nothing else matches.
3. should hardware interaction questions arise they should be consistently tagged [audio-hardware](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-hardware) (instead of [microphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microphone) etc.)
4. "music-" tags should be used only where it is especially about longer tracks of sound. (like [music-composition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-composition) and its synonym [music-production](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-production))
5. "sound-" tags should be used more generic to interact with audible content.

Examples (only audio related tags): <sup>Most are taken from this site.</sup>

- "What Plugin in Browser controls my microphone": [audio-hardware](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-hardware)
- "Dead simple MP3 Player": [sound-player](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-player)
- "Sound Studio Collaboration Software": [music-composition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-composition)
- "Linux tool that lets the media keys control web media sites": - no audio tags -
- "Guitar chord application": [music-composition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-composition)
- "CD-Ripper": [audio-transformation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-transformation)
- "Software to delete music duplicates": [sound-files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-files)
- "Music manager for a mass storage based music player": [sound-files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-files)
- "Songbook text processing": [music-composition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-composition)
- "Software for deleting music...": [sound-files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-files)
- "Purchase iTunes music on Android and sync it to iPod": [sound-files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-files)

This causes the following synonyms (and much more in the same style):

- [music-player](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-player) -> [sound-player](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-player)
- [sound-hardware](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-hardware) -> [audio-hardware](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-hardware)
- [music-transformation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-transformation) -> [audio-transformation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-transformation)