# What is the difference between [sound] and [audio]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

While writing my [most recent question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19929/6834), I noticed that the site has separate tags for [audio](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) and [sound](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound). Is there a difference between these tags, and why aren't they synonyms like they are on other sites? If these tags are intended for different use cases on SoftwareRecs, then could someone please explain the difference and which one to use in the linked question?

Example from Unix & Linux:

[image]

Comment: See also: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/413/the-sound-of-tagging-sorting-out-the-plethora-of-audio-related-tags

Comment: Is there also some tag burnination title competition here? I suggest: [audio] sounds like [sound]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags are now merged (like they are on Stack Overflow, Super User, Unix & Linux, Ask Ubuntu, Apple, …).

Answer (score 3):

I've suggested [the synonym](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/audio/synonyms). As we have this question the second time and the [answer of DVK](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/440/94) has the most upvotes we should synonymize the two.

Vote for the synonym as you see fit.